# error in calling the svg to react native as a component

Tags: reactjs, react-native

the error Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

```
import {ReactComponent as LoginSVG} from '../assets/images/login.svg';
const LoginScreen = ({navigation}) => {
  return (
    
  <SafeAreaView style={{flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center'}}>
      <View style={{paddingHorizontal: 25}}>
        <View style={{alignItems: 'center'}}>
          <LoginSVG />
        </View>

      </View>
</SafeAreaView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work, allow you to pass a width and height prop also;

```
import LoginSVG from '../assets/logo.svg';

...
 <LoginSVG width={'80%'} height={'80%'} />
...
```

**NPM packages**

```
"react-native-svg"
"react-native-svg-transformer"
"react-native-svg-uri"
```